# How to Publish a Meteor Package with the Organization Name?

Tags: meteor

I can't find a simple explanation to publish a meteor package under an organization name. Let's say my username is *lecoupa* and my organization is *gentlenode*. I'm in the package directory.

```
cd /my/package

# what should I do now?
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems that the answer was to specify the name field for `Package.describe()` in `package.js`:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Provides a simple way to render your public gists into a meteor template",
  version: "0.1.0",
  git: 'https://github.com/Gentlenode/meteor-gists',
  name: "gentlenode:meteor-gists"
});
```

And publish:

```
meteor publish --create
```

Comment: That's correct. Additionally, in your Meteor Developer account settings, you'd add your username to the `gentlenode` organization.